# Confused about the parameter of a Poisson Distribution

Tags: statistics

This is an example in my notes,

Suppose typically 220 misprints occur in a 200 page book, find approximately the probability that: 
Then a few probabilities to calculate. The issue is I do not know what the distribution is that defines this, is it $X$ ~ $Po(220)$ or $X$ ~ $Po(200)$ because the probability depends on that, e.g. the probability of no misprints works out as ${e^{ - \lambda }}$.

Comment: You have not shown the detailed question, but it seems that the expected number of misprints per page is $\frac{220}{200}$ and you might see this as a rate parameter

Comment: One of the probabilities is that there are 2 or more misprints on a page. How do I figure that out without the CDF? Now that I know lambda, I can figure out any probability where X = x but 2 or more I don't know how to answer.

Comment: "$2$ or more" is the complement of "$1$ or $0$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that your question will be closed. But I think
I see some of the issues that are causing you trouble. So I will
try to give you some detailed help in case 'Answers' get shut 
down.

**Misprint rate for one page.** In a Poisson problem, you need to make sure the rate $\lambda$ matches the random variable of the problem. @Henry is right that the rate $per\, page$ might be called $\lambda_1 = 220/200 = 1.1.$

So the number of misprints on any one page is the random variable
$X \sim Pois(\lambda = 1.1).$ The probability of 2 or more
misprints on a particular page is 
$$P(X \ge 2) = 1 - P(X \le 1) = 1 - P(X = 0) - P(X = 1).$$
Then you can use the formula $P(X = k) = e^{-\lambda_1}\lambda_1^k/k!$
to find $P(X = 0)$ and $P(X = 1).$

**Misprint rate for 5-page chapter.** By contrast, if you want to know the probability that a five-page chapter has
exactly 5 misprints, then use $Y \sim Pois(\lambda_5 = 5.5)$ 
to find $P(Y = 5) = e^{-5.5}(5.5)^5/5! = 0.1714.$
To find $P(Y \le 5)$ from this PDF formula, you would have to
add together six terms to get $0.5289.$

**Misprint rate for a new 200-page book.** If you have another
200-page book in which misprints occur according to the same
mechanism, then the misprint rate for that book is $\lambda_{200} = 220.$ So if $W \sim Pois(220),$ then the probability that the
new book has between 200 and 230 misprints (inclusive) is
$P(200 \le W \le 230).$ Here you would need to sum 11 terms of the PDF. You might use software, or use a normal approximation.
$W$ is approximately distributed as $Norm(\mu = 220,\, \sigma = \sqrt{220}).$ The answer is close to 0.68. (See the last
software example below.)

**Software.** Most statistical software packages have procedures for finding
Poisson probabilities. In R software the answer to the first
problem can be computed using the PDF `dpois` or the CDF `ppois`
as shown below.

```
 lam.1 = 1.1
 1 - ppois(1, lam.1)
 ## 0.3009707
 1 - dpois(0, lam.1) - dpois(1, lam.1)
 ## 0.3009707
```

The answer to the first part of the second problem can be found from Minitab
software as follows.

```
MTB > pdf 5;
SUBC> pois 5.5.

Probability Density Function 

Poisson with mean = 5.5

x  P( X = x )
5    0.171401
```

To find $P(Y \le 5)$ you would use the following.

```
MTB > cdf 5;
SUBC> pois 5.5.

Cumulative Distribution Function 

Poisson with mean = 5.5

x  P( X <= x )
5     0.528919
```

Perhaps you can match values you get from the Poisson PDF formula
with these answers from software. In practice and in homework
problems, four or five decimal places of accuracy are often enough.
Software gives many places of accuracy and you can round to 
four places if you like.

Finally, here are computations in R for $P(200 \le W \le 230).$ (The notation `220:230` includes
all of the integers from 220 through 230.) Roughly speaking, normal approximations to Poisson probabilities
are often accurate to about two decimal places if $\lambda > 100.$

```
 ppois(230, 220) - ppois(199, 220) 
 ## 0.6804393  # difference of 2 CDFs
 sum(dpois(200:230, 220))
 ## 0.6804393  # sum of 11 PDFs
 pnorm(230.5, 220, sqrt(220)) - pnorm(199.5, 220, sqrt(220))
 ## 0.6770304  # normal approximation (with 'continuity correction')
```

Comment: Wow, what an amazing answer. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped. I answered because I have often taught courses in which students have trouble matching the Poisson rate to the specific problem at hand. Please do not be discouraged by the down-votes and votes to put you question on hold. But you will get better $general$ reaction to questions on this site in the future if you have a clearly stated question with some evidence you have tried to get the answer on your own. Some people on this site are mainly trying to accumulate 'reputation points' at the fastest possible rate and do not favor questions that are not crisply formulated.